# Fabric melting spider juice

Tags: arachnology

I live in the southern rocky mountains of Canada. I was in bed the other night when I saw a small scurrying shadow out of the corner of my eye. The source of the shadow was a small spider (95% sure it was a barn funnel weaver), approx 2cm in diameter. I killed the spider.

Interestingly, what intrigues me is that the place on my bed where I killed the spider the jus of the spider had melted to the sheet (!). How could that happen?

Comment: I tried to cut out the extraneous wording from your question - what do you mean by the spider jus had "melted" to the sheet? Can you clarify?

Comment: I think what he's saying is he smashed the spider and left it overnight on the sheet and it broke down the sheet fibers or left a hole.

Comment: Please look at sheet label and state cotton/linen/other fiber.

Answer (score 2):

Some spiders are known to eat their own silk when breaking down a web and reconstructing it ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_web#:~:text=It%20is%20common%20for%20spiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_web#:%7E:text=It%20is%20common%20for%20spiders)) or even stealing the web of other spiders and eating it (https://frank.itlab.us/photo_essays/papers/Argyrodes_kleptoparasite_spider.pdf). It may very well be that some types are able to digest various silks or other fibres. I'm not aware of any studies that test whether a spider could digest - say - wool or other natural fibres.

If your sheets were silk or other natural fibres, it's feasible that their digestive juices were strong enough to break down your fibres. Who knows, maybe their digestive juices are even strong enough to break down synthetic fibres (unlikely, but I don't know any study that has looked at that).